# How do I rotate a vector?

Tags: javascript, math, vector

If I have `[1, 0]` and I rotate it `90 degrees = 1/2PI radians`, I should get `[0, -1]`. How do I achieve this?

I looked at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and implemented this:

```
var rotateVector = function(vec, ang)
{
    // not right!
    return new PVector(
        vec.x * cos(ang) - vec.y * sin(ang),
        vec.x * sin(ang) + vec.y * cos(ang)
    );
};
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

It doesn't matter if it's degrees or radians, because the geometry remains the same. I use radians right now.

Comment: Is your angle in radians?

Comment: Caveat: most polar systems are **positive** for rotation **counter-clockwise**, and negative for clockwise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your formulas are correct, but you need to use the angle in radians instead of degrees:

```
radians = degrees * (Math.PI/180)
```

And if you want to rotate it clockwise, notice that your angle is -90 degrees instead of 90. Or, consider it 90 but change the formula to:

```
radians = -degrees * (Math.PI/180)
```

**Edit:**

According to your last edit, probably you get the following result:

`[6.123233995736766e-17, -1]`

This is because the computer cannot store "infinite" numbers. But, as you can see that number is very small, so it can be considered `0`. You can round the result.

E.g.:

```
var rotateVector = function(vec, ang)
{
    ang = -ang * (Math.PI/180);
    var cos = Math.cos(ang);
    var sin = Math.sin(ang);
    return new Array(Math.round(10000*(vec[0] * cos - vec[1] * sin))/10000, Math.round(10000*(vec[0] * sin + vec[1] * cos))/10000);
};
```

And test it using:

```
rotateVector([1,0], 90)
```

Result:

```
[0, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I later figured out that `PVector` has a method for it: [`rotate(angle)`](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/pvectorrotatedeg/5559584098877440)